# IndexIgnore in .htaccess to hide directories instead of just files?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Is there an equivalent to IndexIgnore in .htaccess configuration for hiding specific directories (instead of just files)?

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexignore

Comment: The closest thing I've found is setting password protection on a specific folder (AuthUserFile, AuthGroupFile, AuthName, AuthType), which isn't what I want.

Comment: Last time I checked IndexIgnore it was working fine with directories. What platform is this, and what version of apache are you using? Have you tried to put directory and it didn't work?

Comment: Using Apache 2.x.x.  It seems to work now, so I'm not sure what went wrong earlier.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Go look this doc: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexignore

```
IndexIgnore TheNameOfMyFolder* AFile.html ASecondFile.*
```